# Batch Conversion to PDF with LibreOffice in Mac

Tags: mac, libreoffice

I have LibreOffice installed on my new Mac. In Ubuntu you can directly access LibreOffice via command line. How do you access LibreOffice in mac via command line ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out where Libreoffice.app is.   Usually it will be in your Application directory and to access it you would need to add the full path in front of the soffice executable like this /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice .  If you don't want to have to add the full path every time you can add the path /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS  to your /etc/paths file and it should then be available from any terminal program.